# How to make man(1) use the entire terminal width?

Tags: terminal, freebsd, man

I'm on FreeBSD, using a wide xterm with, say, 132 characters per line.
When running

```
$ man man
```

the manual page is formatted to fit an 80 character per line terminal width.
Is there a way to make the formatter (groff, grotty) use a line width I specify?

I read the manuals for man(1) and groff(1) but could not find an appropriate option. I know it can be done, since I have seen it work on some Linux distro.

Comment: There's a `MANWIDTH` environment variable. Could you try setting it?

Comment: @muru You da man! If you make it an answer, I'll bump your rep by 25.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ony my Linux systems, `man 1 man` mentions the `MANWIDTH` environment variable, which, now that I look it up, is also specified in the [FreeBSD `man(1)` manpage](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=man&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD%2011-current):

```
MANWIDTH     If set to a numeric value, used as the width manpages should
             be displayed.  Otherwise, if set to a special value ``tty'',
             and output is to a terminal, the pages may be displayed over
             the whole width of the screen.
```

Comment: also likely permanently configurable in `/etc/man${something here maybe?}.conf`

Comment: @mikeserv apparently `/etc/man.conf` is mentioned in the FreeBSD manpage, but the Ubuntu manpage only mentions `/etc/manpath.config`, and I don't have FBSD system to test what the former does.

Comment: yeah - manpath.conf on my arch system - you can also configure filters and cat file locations there, i think.

Comment: @mikeserv My Arch system's `man 1 man` (and `man manpath`) only mentions a `/etc/man_db.conf`.

Comment: ok *thats* the one - mandb. they shouldnt be very different, i wouldnt think. mine has gnu written all over it, as i recall - pretty standard. manpath.conf is the name of the file you can create per user in `$HOME` - why the distros vary in `/etc` is beyond me.